# React Portal, los modales que creo se cierran si los pulsas cuando no debería

Tags: css, reactjs, modal

Hola que tal estoy haciendo una aplicación con React y uno de mis componentes que son notas, serán clickables, y cuando el usuario haga click en una nota aparecerá entonces un modal con el contenido de la nota.

La funcionalidad ya está hecha y en principio todo guay excepto una cosa, si pulsas en el modal que aparece, este se cierra, esa funcionalidad solo debe ocurrir si pulsas en el botón de cerrar modal, o alrededor del modal, pero no encima del contenido.

**El problema yo pienso que tiene que estar en los estilos 100%**, en algún `z-index` que se me escape, o una `posición absoluta/relativa`... Pero le he dado mil vueltas y nada, no consigo saber por qué ocurre esto.

He probado incluso agregar al modal el estilo `pointerEvents: 'none'`, pero no funciona.

Os dejo el código a ver si veis algo que yo no.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Portal from './Portal'

export default class Modal extends Component {
  render() {

    const { children, toggle, active } = this.props;
    return (
      <Portal>
        {active && (
            <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <div style={styles.window}>
                    <button style={styles.closeBtn} onClick={toggle}>X</button>
                    <div>{children}</div>
                </div>
                <div onClick={toggle} style={styles.background}/>
            </div>
        )}
      </Portal>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
    wrapper:{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 2
    },
    window:{
        borderRadius: 5,
        position: 'absolute',
        background: '#fff',
        padding: 15,
        boxShadow: '2px 2px 10px black',
        zIndex: 4,
        minWidth:620,
        minHeight: 600,
    },
    closeBtn:{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    background:{
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        background: '#000',
        opacity: 0.4,
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 3
    }
}
```

La estructura es :

```
<Portal>
<div>
  <wrapper>
    <window>
      <button>
      <children> (contenido)
    </window>
    <background />
   </wrapper>
</div>
</Portal>
```

Este componente Modal lo utilizo en mi componente Notas

```
import { MdDeleteForever } from 'react-icons/md';
import '../styles/Note.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

const Note = ({ id, text, date, handleDeleteNote, title }) => {  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () =>{
        setActive(!active);
    }
  return (
    <div className="note" onClick={toggle}>
      <h3 className='title'>{title}</h3>
      <span className='description'>{text}</span>
      <div className="note-footer">
        <small>{date}</small>
        <MdDeleteForever 
          className='delete-icon'
          onClick={() => handleDeleteNote(id)}
        />
      </div>
      <Modal active={active} toggle={toggle}>
        <div className="modal-container">
          <h3 className='title'>{title}</h3>
          <span className='description'>{text}</span>
          <div className="note-footer">
            <small>{date}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Note;
```

Imagen para dar algo de contexto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pulsas en la X o en lo gris, el modal se cierra, eso guay, pero si pulsas en lo blanco, en el contenido en rojo, también se cierra. :(

Si se os ocurre algo os leo, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente después de horas entendí el fallo, no puedo agregar el evento onClick en el div contenedor que engloba todo, de alguna forma eso producía el fallo que al tocar el modal se cerrase, sin embargo si el evento onClick que genera el toggle del modal lo llamo en un botón, o cualquier otro elemento de ese contenedor (en este caso en un icono), sí funciona sin ningún tipo de problema.

Código para que veáis el cambio.

```
import { MdDeleteForever, MdRemoveRedEye } from 'react-icons/md';
import '../styles/Note.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

const Note = ({ id, text, date, handleDeleteNote, title }) => {  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () =>{
        setActive(!active);
    }
  return (
    <div className="note">
      <h3 className='title' >{title}</h3>
      <span className='description'>{text}</span>
      <div className="note-footer">
        <small>{date}</small>
        <div className="icons-wrapper">
          <MdRemoveRedEye 
            className='icons'
            onClick={toggle}
          />
          <MdDeleteForever 
            className='icons'
            onClick={() => handleDeleteNote(id)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Modal active={active} toggle={toggle}>
        <div className="modal-container">
          <h3 className='title'>{title}</h3>
          <span className='description'>{text}</span>
          <div className="note-footer">
            <small>{date}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Note;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]